# How to setup jasmine for typescript project

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I need some guidance of how to set up unit testing of TypeScript project with Jasmine.

Test spec file looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
import {Mediator} from '../../../services/remoting/Mediator';

describe('Mediator', () =>
{
    let mediator: Mediator;

    beforeEach(() => 
    {
        mediator = new Mediator();
    });

    it('blah blah', () =>
    {
        expect(mediator.TEST).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

I use npm jasmine module to run tests. jasmine.json is pointing to the built JS spec files like this:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "build/spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

The build spec file looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
define(["require", "exports", '../../../services/remoting/Mediator'], function (require, exports, Mediator_1) {
    describe('factory: Mediator', function () {
        var mediator;
        beforeEach(function () {
            mediator = new Mediator_1.Mediator();
        });
        it('should have defined all required fields', function () {
            expect(mediator.ExecuteQuery).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
//# sourceMappingURL=Mediator.spec.js.map
```

when I try to run tests jasmine complains over undefined 'define' function:

```
ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

I have tried to search on the TypeScript + Jasmine but there is not much information (and I do not want to use full VisualStudio). So I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction of how to set typescript + jasmine and where my mistake is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are compiling using the `--module amd` flag, which is designed for asynchronous modules (like when you use RequireJS).

If you are running on Node, you need to supply `--module commonjs`. This will result in the following output:

```
var mediator_1 = require('../../../services/remoting/Mediator');
```

(Although the name of the variable may change as it creates a name on the fly for you when compiling ES6 style imports down).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Its works with your suggestion. My project is an SPA application that will be run in browser. I do develop it in VSCode + node.js to run npm packages and such. As far as I understand amd is more suitable for browser based apps, but I do develop using node.js tools -> that in turn requires common.js. What should be used?

Comment: An interesting conundrum :) You will want to compile with `--module amd` for use in the browser if you are using RequireJS (but continue to use `--module commonjs` for your local development). The two systems have different module patterns.

Comment: The thing is that I do not use RequireJS. All I use so far is plain TypeScript. And then I wanted to add some unit tests when error comes up. If I understand correctly when I compile with -commonjs flag the functions used (like 'require') are already part of node.js. And therefore no error occurs. When I compile with -amd flag then functions like 'define' are by default provided under the hood by browser but not by node.js. Is it the case?

Comment: If you are targeting ES6, module loading is a part of that. If you are targeting earlier versions (like ES5) you will need to supply a module loader like RequireJS. You can check browser support for ES6 imports here (as of May 2015: none): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import